# No Response when Selected Item in a Spinner Widget(Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, spinner

The code below retrieves data from an xml page and stores the data in an ArrayList called namesList. The elements inside the namesList are being assigned to be displayed in a spinner dropdown list. My problem is that whenever I choose an item in a spinner, nothing shows up on the console. (It is suppose to display a message, as shown in the code) Once a while this error message:

```
Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already
been disposed.
```

gets displayed. Does anyone know how do I solve this problem?

```
            boolean done = false;
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
            {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                        try
                        {


                     URL url = new URL("http://www.xmlWebsite.ca");
                            URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
                            input = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

//....................................

                            namesList.add(name);
                            done=true;

                        }

                    }
                    catch (IOException e1)
                    {
                        System.out.println("The URL is not valid.");
                        System.out.println(e1.getMessage());
                    }
                    catch (XmlPullParserException e)
                    {
                        System.out.println("xml error");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        thread.start();
    while (done == false)
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(1500);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, namesList);
                    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), parent.getItemAtPosition(position) + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                System.out.println(parent.getItemAtPosition(position) + " selected!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
            {

            }
        });
    }
```

I added a while loop to wait for the thread to finish. I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way of doing it.

Comment: It is amazing that you can see items in your spinner because this code has a concurrency problem. You are running a thread that fetches names, puts them in namesList while your spinner does not wait until it finishes. Where are the names in the spinner coming from ?

Comment: I got the names from the namesList arraylist that were retrieve from the xml webpage. Ya, I see a concurrency problem here, and maybe that's why I got that error message.

Comment: I updated the code. I added a while loop that waits for the thread to finish. I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way of doing it.

Comment: check wether the name list is empty and play with asynctask instead of thread

Answer (score 0):

Do you know about [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)? :-)

Do your network actions in **doInBackground** method of it and do adapter and action listener work in **onPostExecute** method. That is the best way of dealing that.

Doing that, you don't need to create separate Thread and use loop to wait for the network actions to get finished. You may also display progress dialog during the time of getting data from XML file.